# Access point suggestion for mobile devices

Tags: wifi, access-point

My Verizon wifi router (MI424WR Rev.I) which I have installed in the basement is not enough to cover all rooms upstairs and around the house. I'm looking for any suggestion for a wifi access point which I will install upstairs somewhere in the middle of my house and connect with VZ router via cat5. Price range below ($100).

I'm not sure if [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833156232) one is ok.